# Using DLR from Unmanaged Code

Tags: .net, delphi, ironpython, unmanaged, ironruby

Is it possible to call managed code, specifically IronRuby or IronPython from unamanaged code such as C++ or Delphi?

For example, we have an application written in Delphi that is being moved to C#.NET  We'd like to provide Ruby or Python scripting in our new application to replace VBSCRIPT.  However, we would need to provide Ruby/Python scripting in the old Delphi application.  Is it possible to use the managed dlls provided by IronRuby/IronPython from Delphi code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.  Delphi for Win32 example here: http://interop.managed-vcl.com/
Shows how to use a C# as well as a Delphi.NET assembly from Delphi for Win32.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to host the CLR or DLR in unmanaged code as it is a COM component. From that point you can load the managed assemblies you need to interact with.

From MSDN: [Hosting the Common Language Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9x0wh2z3.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Why not embed CPython instead, which has an API intended to be used directly from C/C++. You lose the multiple language advantage but probably gain simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. That is possible using [Com Callable Wrappers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f07c8z1c.aspx). Basically you are enabling your .Net classes to be called through COM/ActiveX from your win32 code (Delphi or C++).

Answer (score 2):

I use [Unmanaged Exports](http://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports) to created interface to IronPython script engine in C#. Be carefull when you use .NET code from Win32 Delphi - you have to use `Set8087CW($133F);` to change floating point exception behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [Hydra](http://www.remobjects.com/product/?id=%7BB6BD1030-F630-4DA8-9018-73C03265A0EF%7D) from RemObjects? I have no experience with it, but from the intro, it looks relevant.